# How i can solve this error while during DB Seeding Laravel Roles

Tags: php, laravel, roles

i'm a laravel beginner and i use laravel-roles from github. I try to do the setup but with the step: php artisan db:seed i get the following error:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException

Target class [Database\Seeders\DatabaseSeeder] does not exist.

at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:811
807|
808| try {
809| $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
810| } catch (ReflectionException $e) {

    811| throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
    812| }
    813|
    814| // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
    815| // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

  +25 vendor frames

26 artisan:37
Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Have anyone a idea why and how can i solve this problem? Thank you very much ;)

Comment: Target class` [Database\Seeders\DatabaseSeeder]` does not exist.

Comment: Does the file `DatabaseSeeder` exist in the `Database\Seeders` directory of your application and is it named correctly?

Comment: are you using laravel 8 ?

Comment: @HijenHEK: I'm using Laravel 7.30.4

Comment: @Unflux no, the file doesn't exist here. The DatabaseSeeder.php is at database/seeds/

Comment: @hw24 Then move `DatabaseSeeder.php` to `Database\Seeders` as Laravel expects it to be there.

Answer (score 0):

you either

- dont have the file DatabaseSeeder.php at Database/seeders/
  or
- the class is not accessible due to naming or namespace issue

i just had the same issue after using tcg/voyager package and its usually an autoload issue where composer cannot find the class

installing the package named laravel-role wont affect your databse seeder file, it demands to add some seeds so it shouldnt affect your file unless you copied exactly what they put into their readme on github then you overrided your file , and what you are missing is the namespace .

add this to the top of DatabaseSeeder.php in database/seeders

```php
namespace Database\Seeders;
```

then run

```sh
composer dump-autoload
```

finally seed again

```sh
php artisan db:seed
```

#### Edit :

make sure to update your DatabaseSeeder.php importing the right namespaces for all your calls

```
use  Database\Seeders\PermissionsTableSeeder ;

public function run() {
  $this->call([
     PermissionsTableSeeder::class,
  ]);
}
```

**[laravel 7](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/seeding#writing-seeders)**

- put all your seed classes under the same folder as the DatabaseSeeder.php
- no need to use namespaces
- no need to require anything
- call all classes directly

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call([
            PermissionsTableSeeder::class, 
        ])
    }
}
```

Comment: When i add to the top of DatabaseSeeder.php (namespace Database\Seeders) i get the followeing error: Target class [Database\Seeders\PermissionsTableSeeder] does not exist. I think the problem is, that the DatabaseSeeder.php is in seeders and the rest of the files in /seeds

Comment: if you are using laravel 8 , seeds is not useful anymore , it shouldnt give you an error but move all seed files to database/Seeders/

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer. The file DatabaseSeeder.php is at database/seeds/ and contain the following:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Database\Seeders\PermissionsTableSeeder;
use Database\Seeders\RolesTableSeeder;
use Database\Seeders\ConnectRelationshipsSeeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

            $this->call(PermissionsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(RolesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(ConnectRelationshipsSeeder::class);
            //$this->call('UsersTableSeeder');

        Model::reguard();
    }
}
```

At /database/seeders/ i have four files ConnectRelationshipsSeeder.php, PermissionsTableSeeder.php, RolesTableSeeder.php, UsersTableSeeder.php
So there path is differnt must than the namespace Database\Seeds or namespace Database\Seeders?

Thank you very much.